# How to check callout URL is active or not?

Tags: rest-api, rest

I had created a rest service in salesforce which makes a callout to URL.I need to check whether the URL is active or not.

How this can be done in salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a request and if you get response in 5xx then server is down or there are some server error.

So that you can check if URL is active.

[Status code 5xx](http://www.websitepulse.com/kb/5xx_http_status_codes.html)

Comment: Like I thought you have to do a callout to test the URL as there is no static way of testing it.

Comment: @DaveHumm Yes I don't think we have any static way.